# How to add a listener on edittext in a custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, listener

I want to implement a dialog to receive password input and validate it. Now I have defined a dialog class and  oncreate function will setContentView using my own layout file.

```
    MyDialog class {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.ms_pdf_viewer_password_layout);
    }
}
```

Here is XML

```
<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:hint="Please enter the password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"/>
```

I create a dialog object in the fragment and I want to handle enter button pressing and validate the input password, but the listener is not working,actionID is cannot be printed out. I think maybe I don't get the editText object rightly.

```
 Dialog dialog = new PdfPasswordDialog(getActivity());
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ms_pdf_viewer_password_layout, container, false);
EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);



editText.setOnEditorActionListener(
            new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    Log.i(sClassTag,"actionID is "+actionId);
```

How can I add a listener on the edittext in custom dialog to handle password input? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use `TextWatcher`

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve it by using this line

```
 EditText editText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

after

```
  dialog.show().
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change or manipulate the text or check the entered text when a new character entered, you can use a `TextWatcher` here is an example for you:

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // when the change is done
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ms_pdf_viewer_password_layout);
dialog.setTitle("Any Title You Want");
EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Now try the onClickListener.